# What configuration options are worth reviewing in Cassandra if one is using SSDs instead of spinning disk?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I just replaced a Cassandra cluster with brand new SSDs instead of spinning disks. What configuration options would you recommend that I review? Feel free to post links to blog posts/presentations if you know of any (yes, I've Googled).

Answer (score 3):

Based on a quick look through the `cassandra.yaml`, there are three that I see right away:

`memtable_flush_writers` : It is set to 2 by default, but the text above the setting indicates that "If your data directories are backed by SSD, you should increase this to the number of cores."

`trickle_fsync` : Forces the OS to run an `fsync` to flush the dirty buffers during sequential writes.  The text above the setting indicates that setting it to `true` is "Almost always a good idea on SSDs; not necessarily on platters."

`concurrent_compactors` : The number of simultaneous compactions allowed.  Just like the `memtable_flush_writers` setting, the text above indicates that SSD users should set it to the number of system cores.

Also, according to the DataStax documentation on [Selecting hardware for enterprise implementations](https://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/planning/architecturePlanningHardware_c.html):

> Unlike spinning disks, it's all right to store both commit logs and SSTables are on the same mount point.

Comment: also compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec can be increased (might wanna wait to do it in response to finding your getting behind though)